# Flash eats focus and standard Firefox's hotkeys does not work. How to fix it? I press Ctrl+T but nothing happens

Tags: firefox, flash, hotkeys, focus, seamonkey

I want to use standard browser hotkeys even when focus is inside adobe flash. How I can get it?
I want e.g. Ctrl+T, Ctrl+W, Ctrl+R, Ctrl+N, Ctrl+L, Ctrl+F6, F11 ...
I need cross-platform solution, because I use different operating systems, but currently I use Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your operating system?

Comment: I need cross-platform solution.

Comment: sometimes alt+tabbing away and back to get focus on the window, doesn't work everywhere though

Comment: You want your key combos to work in your browser while another program has focus?

Comment: @Ravenous No. Focus is within embedded flash object within Firefox browser. Normally combos must work in this situation. E.g. they work in current versions of Google Chrome and Midori. But not in Firefox.

Comment: @ratchetfreak It is bad solution. Browser combos must work immediately.

Comment: a double alt+tab is pretty fast if you practice it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution of problem of eating standard hotkeys by Adobe Flash.
It is extension/addon [Focus Regainer](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/focus-regainer/). It works both in Firefox & Seamonkey. It work both on Linux & Windows, and maybe on Mac OS X.

Focus Regainer allow you to use standard hotkeys when focus is within flash plugin:

1) `Ctrl+T` for open new tab

2) `Ctrl+W` for close current tab

3) `Ctrl+R` for refreshing page

4) `Ctrl+Q` for quit Firefox

5) `Ctrl+L` for focus URLbar/awesomebar

6) `Ctrl+N` for open new browser window

7) `F11` for fullscreen mode

and other.

In Mac Os X you must use `Cmd(Meta)` button instead `Ctrl`.

If single pressing of some hotkey does not work, then you must use double pressing. It is Adobe Flash plugin limitation.

Alternatively you can use hotkey `Ctrl+Esc` or `Ctrl+F12` to remove focus from embedded flash.
`Alt+Esc` or `Alt+F12` are for moving focus back to flash object, but not always work, e.g. because html page can have multiple flash objects.

P.S.: Technical information about problem in my question with eating browser standard hotkeys is in [Mozilla Bug 78414](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78414).